# Make a custom view mode default

Tags: theming, entities

I made a custom view mode in Display Suite and I would like to use it as the default view mode for a given content type. Can anybody enlighten me as to how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way i set the 'fullpage' view_mode of a node as default:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_view_mode_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {
  // Set default view mode.
  if (isset($context['entity']->nid)) {
    if ($context['entity_type'] == 'node' && $context['entity']->type == 'YOUR_CTYPE' && $view_mode == 'full') {
      $view_mode = 'fullpage';
    }
  }
}
```

It actually sets the view_mode to 'fullpage' when in full mode (default), but you could ommit that part (&& $view_mode == 'full').

Remember that 'fullpage' is the machine name of my view_mode and 'YOUR_CTYPE' is the machine name of your content type.

Not sure if this will work with Display suite though...

Comment: DS is for Display Suite - i just edited the original question and I'll try your suggesion

Comment: Yes it does! 
Just for the record:
I created a custom module in sites/all/modules/custom/, created an .info and a .module file, to which I pasted the code above, replacing the module name with the one I chose and YOUR_CTYPE with the *machine name* of the content type (I emphasize that because i first just typed the human name and it obviously did not work). Thanks!

Comment: And it seems to work consistently with Display Suite, i can change the default view mode in code to some new one created in DS.

Comment: Great, there was no particular reason this won't work with DS, just never used it.Glad it helped.